# point or arrow on variables/methods in Qt

Tags: qt, variables, methods

can you please tell me the difference between the "point" and the "arrow", for example :

`file.open`

and

`->start()` (with QThread)

i thought the arrow was used for "methods", whereas the "point" is used for "attributes", but `open` for example `is` a method.

thanks for your answer

Comment: You should learn C++ before starting to use Qt (or any other C++ framework).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just for Qt, the . is used when the variable in question is referencing the actual instance of the type/class.

Example:

```
QLabel label(QString("Hello"));
label.show();
```

The -> is used when the variable is a pointer that can hold the address of the type/class.

Example:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(QString("Hello"));
label->show();
```

Comment: Thank buster, i tried the second example, i've got an error to "convert from const char* to qlabel*" with the pointer. Would you know why? Also, i've only seen so far the use of `QString string` without the pointer, if i try with a pointer, it ends up with the same error `cannot convert const char* to QString* in initialization`. Any idea? thanks

Comment: Yeah, I think you may have to initialize a QLabel with a QString.. I will edit it now.

Comment: thank you buster for the edit, and do you know why one way is preferred to the other? i mean, i'm learning c++ and it seems that every variable is a pointer, but in Qt, i sometimes see variables as `QLabel label` or `Qstring string`, where i would have used a pointer instead...

Comment: it's a long story, but it could be thought of as a strategic move to declare a pointer instead of a variable of the class type.  One Example (as there are thousands) When you declare a pointer `QString *string` you reserve the amount of memory for an address of a QString, but when you declare `QString string` you reserve a pointer at `&string` and the amount of memory that a QString would need.  So there are strategic instances in which you would want to declare only a pointer. Also when you use pointers you can do pointer addition.  However, there really is no single answer that I know.

Answer (score 1):

-> is used for pointers. if x is declared as pointer to sth, x-> is used for attributes, otherwise . is used.

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(tr("Heyy"));
QHBoxLayout hbox = new QHBoxLayout;

label->show();
hbox.addWidget("foo");
```

Comment: this is not a feature of Qt or any other Framework btw, it's C++. As @Flavius advises, you'd better learn C++ before using with Qt, I think..